# Tuning Binomial Logistic Regression parameter in pyspark;

Tags: python, pyspark

I try to tunning the parameter of Tuning Binomial Logistic Regression parameter in pyspark, but the result didn't change at all
[Fist parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2oxa.png)

[Second parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFqhP.png)

## First Logistic regression model without parameters.

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression

train_data, test_data = pipe_df.randomSplit([0.7,0.3])
print("Training Dataset Count: " + str(train_data.count()))
print("Test Dataset Count: " + str(test_data.count()))

# First Logistic regression model without parameters.
lr_model = LogisticRegression(featuresCol='features',labelCol='state')

lr_model = lr_model.fit(train_data)

results = lr_model.transform(test_data)
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(
    labelCol="state", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="accuracy")
print ("Test set accuracy = " + str(accuracy))
```

## Accuracy

### Test set accuracy = 0.6401755241345685

## Second Logistic regression model with new parameters.

```
mlr = LogisticRegression(featuresCol='features',labelCol='state', maxIter=60, regParam=0.8, elasticNetParam=0.8, family="multinomial")

lrModel = mlr.fit(train_data)

results2 = lrModel.transform(test_data)
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol="state", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="accuracy")
accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(results2)
print ("Test set accuracy = " + str(accuracy))
```

## Accuracy

Test set accuracy = 0.6401755241345685

Comment: Can you please add the code to the question? Most of us don't enjoy working with images.